# PHP session_id() being overridden

Tags: php, session

I really don't know how to describes this, but here goes. I'm trying to make a Login for an online multiplayer game (cluedo to be exact) that is written using mainly the LAMP stack (php,js,etc), and creating a session when someone logs in/registers works for me and all and I even save it to a sql database, but it seems that as soon as a next user Logs in/registers the session id to the previous user is overridden to the new ones details. In other words they both now have the same session for some reason.

My Game LogIn basically:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Game Setup</title>
        </head>

     <body>
         <header>
             <h1>Game Setup</h1>
         </header>



//My form for user details and character select
         <form name="Registration" id=Form1 action="Lobby.php" method="POST">
         <fieldset>
             <legend>Player information:</legend>
             <label for="Pid">Player Name(required): </label><br>
             <input autofocus type="text" id="Pid" name="Pid" placeholder="Player ID" required><br>
             <label for="Avatar">Character(required):</label><br>
             <select name="Avatar">
                <option value="Miss White">Miss White</option>
                <option value="Col Mustard">Col Mustard</option>
                <option value="Miss Scarlet">Miss Scarlet</option>
                <option value="Mr Green">Mr Green</option>
                <option value="Madame Plum">Madame Plum</option>
                <option value="Benjamin Blue">Benjamin Blue</option>
            </select><br><br>
             <input type="submit" value="Register">
           </fieldset>  
         </form>

     </body>
```

and the lobby (where I wait for someone to press game start or for more people to register)

```
<?php 
    session_start() ;
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION["UserName"]=$_POST['Pid'];
    $_SESSION["Avatar"]=$_POST['Avatar'];
 ?>
 <?php require 'DatabaseConnect.php' ?>
 <?php include 'Users.php' ?>

<?php
$PlayerID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Pid']);
$PlayerChar = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Avatar']);
$SesID = session_id();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (UserName, Avatar, sessionID)
    VALUES ('$PlayerID', '$PlayerChar','$SesID')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Welcome $PlayerID , currently in Lobby: <br>";

        $User = new Users();
        $User->setUserName($_SESSION['UserName']);
        $User->setAvatar( $_SESSION['Avatar']);
        $User->isPlaying = false;
        $_SESSION['User'] = serialize($User);

        ?>
        <html>
            <body>
        <div id="Players"> </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src ="Display.js"></script>
            </body>
         </html>

       <?php 

        }
        else {
        if($conn->errno == 1062){//when a userName or Character already in use
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
             $result = $conn->query($sql);
             $sql = "ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = ".$result->num_rows;
             $conn->query($sql);

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('ERROR :Username or Character already in use!')</script>";
           echo" <script>
                window.location = 'LogIn.php';
                </script>";


        }
    }

 ?>
```

and then the Display.js runs in a loop until either 6 people connect or a user presses start. It also displays everyone currently waiting for a game by outputting the SQL database, but I don't think that code is necessary to add, but then when that's done I go to the Cluedo.php page and if I echo session_id() there on two different browsers(same machine) I get the same session_id()

```
 <?php 
    session_start() ;

 ?>
 <?php require 'DatabaseConnect.php' ?>
 <?php include 'Users.php' ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Cluedo</title>
    </head>

 <body>
        <?php 
                 $User = unserialize($_SESSION['User']);
                 echo session_id();
        ?>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Also I'm using XAMPP and running it all locally at the moment so don't know if there's a problem there maybe?

Here's an example of my database with the saved values, the table saves unique sessions however when the session_id() is echoed at the Cluedo.php page it is always the last registered user:

[UserTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bBf2.png)

Comment: @RyanVincent I'm not sure I explained the problem correctly or misunderstanding you, but I don't have a problem with creating the session or saving it, it just seems that as soon as a new player logs in the old players session is set to the new ones and I don't want that. Also I save a userID in the database as well that auto increments on each successful registration.

Comment: Also to note I mainly just want the $User class variable in the Cluedo.php page because I set and save everything before going to that page and once it's there I don't even really need the session anymore, but the problem is that the session is the same for each instance of the browsers I have open.

Comment: just curious, why do you use `session_regenerate_id();` as they already have a unique working session? What are the advantages of doing this? Why are you not giving the `user game session` a GUID that is certain to not clash with anything?

Comment: @RyanVincent I used that to test some stuff (that is redundant code now). I thought if I could forcibly create a new id then the sessions might not be the same, but it didn't work. Also I don't think that it is clashing it's more like user 1 becomes user 2, but user 2 is still user 2.

Comment: I am not sure why you link 'PHP session id' to 'user game session id'? imo, with the most important part being 'PHP session id'.  imo,   'PHP session' is temporary store with a lifetime of minutes and not much else imo, It certainly isn't useful as the 'master source' of anything really important. It is useful for checking that stuff is valid for the last few minutes.

Comment: @RyanVincent I stored it to see if unique ones were being generated at all or not. Also as I said I simply need to get the $User class variable from the lobby to the Cluedo.php page and have it actually be that players information cause at the moment everyones playing as the same person basically, so when I'm on the Cluedo.php I can't say something like SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName=$User->getName(). I don't know who I am playing as without the session being unique

Comment: nah keep them, it could help other people understand my problem